# Class path resource not found randomly

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, tomcat, classpath

We have integrated Spring with Hibernate and Struts2 in Eclipse and have been getting these errors when running the build:

```
14-Oct-2011 10:37:27 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Test.hbm.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
...
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [Test.hbm.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
...
```

Our mapping in applicationContext.xml is:

```
<property name="mappingResources" value="Test.hbm.xml" />
```

Test.hbm.xml is in ***/build/classes***, and we have tried putting it in */WEB-INF*, */src*, and even created a new source folder called */hibernate* and dumped it in and it worked on only a few machines.

The first time we wrote it, it showed this error. And then we copied the exact same code into a new project, it suddenly worked. On some machines, it works; on others, it shows this error.

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Let me know if any other information is needed.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a build-time error. It's a run-time one. Intermittent failures of that sort indicate a problem with your build, though. As a classpath resource, Test.hbm.xml must be in a classpath location when you run your app. Where exactly that is depends on how you're running it, but /WEB-INF will never work for a webapp, and a random /hibernate folder is unlikely to work, too, unless you've done some custom configuration to make that a classpath resource or make it build to one. For a more definitive answer, you'll need to provide more detail about what you're running and how you're building it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's in /build/classes also. I am still a newbie to this but I'll try my best to describe it. I created a dynamic web project in Eclipse with Tomcat 6 as a server, followed a tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-spring2/  to create applicationContext, put a spring listener in web.xml and clicked on the "run on server" button. The random /hibernate folder worked though; we did a "configure build path" and added it as a "source". What other details can I provide?

Comment: Do you have any other ideas? :(

Comment: One idea is that you need to be using a build tool and not just depending on Eclipse. As you're probably seeing, local variations in IDE configuration can affect how the project builds and runs. A build tool gives you (or at least should give you) a stable, canonical way of building and running the project which always works the same way. By order of preference, I recommend Gradle, Maven, or--as a distant third--Ant.